# Does indexer:reindex need "var", "generated" and "pub/static" to be writable?

Tags: magento2, reindex, static-content

I would like to know if, when doing "php bin/magento indexer:reindex" the folders "var", "generated" and "pub/static" have to be writable ?

Alternatively, does reindexing only work at database level?

All advice and opinions are welcome! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my knowledge, indexing is done only on database level.

Magento Indexer tracks database changes for a certain entity and performs re-index if required.

So, if we talk about:

```
var: it contains cache,log report etc 
generated: contains class files
pub/static : Static view files
```

For testing purpose, I have set `sudo chmod -R 444 .` to `var`,`generated` and `pub/static` folder then ran indexer and it worked!

You can check more detail at: [official document](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/indexing.html)